# Java - Validation if row number already exists in arrayList,

Tags: java, validation, oop, arraylist

I want my program to check if the item entered is already in arrayList which is stored within my file ChessList.java, if so produce error and loop back to question else accept number and move on.

Reason being I only want one number to be selected in a row. 
Say my program asks for Piece 1, row number and USER ENTERS **5** 
Then when program loops to piece 2, row number cannot accept 5 again and would produce error.

Therefore, two pieces cannot be contained within in the same row.

Any suggestions how I would go about this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read your code because there's a lot of it, but it just sounds like you want something like

```
while(true){
    int number = getNumber();
    if(list.contains(number){
        System.out.println("That number is already in the list. Try again");
    else{
        list.add(number);
        break;
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to store it as a Set, which does not store duplicates.